# I get an error when I try to finish an arguement in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I try to debug the app it gives me an error at the of the arguement saying expression expected

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
     Contact contact = new Contact(dbHandler.getContactsCount(),
           String.valueOf(nameTxt.getText()), String.valueOf(phoneTxt.getText()),
           String.valueOf(emailTxt.getText()), String.valueOf(addressTxt.getText()),);
```

Comment: I think the actual error would be helpful

Comment: The joys of copy-pasting .... String.valueOf(addressTxt.getText()), <-- you have an extra comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a comma at the end of the line:

```
new Contact(........., String.valueOf(addressTxt.getText()),);
                                                           ^
```

You have to remove it

Comment: I did and i get an error in the whole arguement saying {Contact() in contact cannot be applied to  Contact}